# Logstash logs to Grafana without Elasticsearch

Tags: logstash, prometheus, grafana, filebeat

Hello i have filebeat which is collecting logs and it is connected with logstash.

My idea is to show logs from logstash to Grafana.

Is there any option to send logstash logs directly to prometheus or grafana?

In my solution i dont want to use elasticsearch. I found some logstash exporter but that is for status of logstash not for logs.

Answer (score 1):

Grafana is a visualization tool that reads the data from a data source, you will need to store your logs in one of the supported data sources, `prometheus` and `elasticsearch` are just two of the supported data sources.

To send your logs from Logstash to Prometheus you would need an output plugin, but there isn't an official plugin for it, it seems that a [third party plugin](https://github.com/SpencerMalone/logstash-output-prometheus) exists, but it is currently in beta and maybe it still do not have all the features that you want.

Comment: As i noticed with this plugin you can create metrics for prometheu. For example number of logs. But i want to have the log messages and severity etc

Answer (score 0):

Grafana, by itself, doesn't store any data (besides users/dashboards, etc.). Storing the raw logs in Prometheus is not recommended. Prometheus doesn't handle well high cardinality labels, and each different log line would generate a new value for the label. And this is assuming that you transform your log line into a set of labels and send that to Prometheus (again, don't do this).

That being said, you might want to give it a try to [Loki](https://grafana.com/oss/loki/). This a new~ish system that (as described by its authors) "Like Prometheus but for your logs". They even support a query language LogQL that is a subset of PromQL, and you can even extract metrics from the logs while storing the logline. Ingestion is usually through Promtail but Loki has an HTTP endpoint that can be used to push the logs.

The data model from Loki is quite similar: a set of labels, a timestamp, and a logline. Grafana ships with out of the box support for Loki, and it is improving with each release.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to use Loki instead of Filebeat and Logstash but i have problem because i can see my logs in Explore panel but the logs are not showed in the Graph panel

Comment: The graph panel is focused on graphing metrics, not logs, what you can do is _extract_ metrics from your logs. The good news is that while you're in the graph panel you do have access to all labels. Have you looked at the Logs panel for displaying the log lines?

Comment: as i can see in the video here: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/loki/

there are logs and in the graphic you can see in which time the log appears.

In my solution now i can see only the bottom table with all logs and the graphic is empty..

Comment: Strange, may I ask which version of Grafana are you running? I'm using v6.6.2 (latest stable release and for me, it looks like this, while in the "Logs" tab in the Explore section: https://share.getcloudapp.com/7KuRPK20 You should get a small histogram of the count of events per time.

Comment: I am using Grafana 6.6.1.. I will try with the newest version of Grafana.